# Relation between SE of matrix mean and SEs of row/column means

Tags: standard-error

I have a matrix $Sample$ of sampled random values.
I can calculate the mean of all values in the matrix and the corresponding standard error $SE_{Sample}$ of that mean (not sure whether that's a correct thing to do).
I can also calculate the per-row/per-column means and corresponding inter-row/inter-column standard errors ($SE_{Rows}$/$SE_{Columns}$).
All those standard errors are different.

I want to understand how is the inter-element standard error related to the inter-row and inter-column standard errors.

**Update**: A better explanation:
I have a data sample from a 2D random process - a matrix: $Sample$ of size $N_p$x$N_q$.

I see that the values have some relation between the values. I suspect that the values depend on some hidden random variables that are "column/row bound". E.g. $$Sample_{p,q} \sim N(PMean_p, PVar_p) + N(QMean_q, QVar_q) + N(0, NoiseVar)$$, where $PMean_p, PVar_p, QMean_q, QVar_q$ were all sampled from some hidden well-behaved distributions.

My goal is to estimate the mean of the process and the confidence intervals of my mean estimate. The best guess for the mean of the process, given the sample is just the mean value of the sample matrix. But we can also calculate the same quantity as the mean of column means or the mean of row means: $$Mean = \sum_{p,q}{Sample_{p,q}} = \sum_{p}{(\sum_{q}{Sample_{p,q}})} = \sum_{q}{(\sum_{p}{Sample_{p,q}})}$$. Similarly, I can calculate the sample variance, the variance of the row means and the variance of the column means. These quantities are different. I want to use these sample variances to calculate the confidence intervals of my estimation of the process mean.

Comment: If the values aren't independent, how do you calculate the standard error of the mean? Hopefully you're not using a calculation that assumes exactly what you state isn't so...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the "per-row/per-column" means. A replicable example would help.  Having said that, I doubt there is a neat relationship between the various standard errors you are interested in, as the formula for a standard error is non-linear, so there is no simple relationship between standard errors of sub-parts versus the standard error of the whole, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @Tim I've made an edit to try explaining the question better.

Comment: @Glen_b I do not know how to calculate the full sample standard error properly in my case and that's what I want to do. I feel that within each row (column), the values are independent. I also feel that the row (column) means are independent. I though that that make sit OK to calculate the inter-row (inter-column) standard errors using the usual formula.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. A simple place to start would be $Sample_{p,q} = f(p) + g(q) + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon ~ N(0, \sigma^2)$, where $p$ and $Q$ are categorical variables (i.e,. your data setup with $pq$ rows, and three variables, the mean, p, and q). Then, the standard error of the residuals is what you want. If this is not relevant, it means I am not understanding your question.